# Randomly sample non-empty column values for each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random, sample

For each row, I would like to randomly sample k columnar indices that correspond to non-null values.

If I start with this dataframe,

```
A = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, np.nan, 3, 5],
    [np.nan, 2, np.nan, 7],
    [4, 8, 9]
])
>>> A
    0   1   2   3
0   1.0 NaN 3.0 5.0
1   NaN 2.0 NaN 7.0
2   4.0 8.0 9.0 NaN
```

If I wanted to randomly sample 2 non-null values for each row and change them to the value -1, one way that can be done is as follows:

```
B = A.copy()

for i in A.index:
    s = A.loc[i]
    s = s[s.notnull()]
    col_idx = random.sample(s.index.tolist(), 2)
    B.iloc[i, col_idx] = -1

>>> B
    0   1   2   3
0   -1.0    NaN -1.0    5.0
1   NaN -1.0    NaN -1.0
2   -1.0    -1.0    9.0 NaN
```

Is there a better way to do this natively in Pandas that avoids having to use a for loop? The `pandas.DataFrame.sample` method seems to keep the number of columns that are sampled in each row constant. But if the dataframe has empty holes, the number of non-null values for each row wouldn't be constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case do `stack` the `groupby` with `sample` ,change the value `update` back

```
s = A.stack().groupby(level=0).sample(n=2)
s[:] = -1
A.update(s.unstack())
A
Out[122]: 
     0    1    2    3
0  1.0  NaN -1.0 -1.0
1  NaN -1.0  NaN -1.0
2 -1.0  8.0 -1.0  NaN
```